# Logged in users still see login page (django auth)

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using `django.contrib.auth` to handle user authentication in my django project. In order to log in, I have

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

# ...

url(r'^login/', login, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/', logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
```

in my main project's `urls.py`.

So far, so good. However, I notice that *after* logging in, if I access `/login/`, I still see the login page, and am able to log in as another user. This seems like counter-intuitive behavior -- most websites will either show an error or redirect you to the homepage if you attempt to access the login page while logged in.

**I'm using the builtin models / views, and so as far as I know I have no easy way of altering the views.** Is there a simple way of gaining this functionality (i.e. preventing access to the login form if logged in), or is the best way simply to modify the template to only show the form if not logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You hide content within the `template.html` using `templateTags` like so:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>Only a logged in User can view</p>
{% else %}
  <p>Only a logged out User can view</p>
{% endif %}
```

[EDIT]

If you would like to then redirect the user before the web page is rendered, then you can do that in the view.

```
def myView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'logged_in_view.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'logged_out_view.html')
```

Comment: The potential problem of putting this into the template is that should a logged-in user submit the form regardless, the submission would still be considered valid. For example, say I open up the login page in two tabs, log in to one of them, the submission into the other tab should not be processed.

Comment: @Mala, I put an edit on how to redirect then before the html page is rendered.

Answer (score 10):

Simply you can write you login url as this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html", redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:
I create 'my_login':

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(#...home)
    else:
        return login(request, 'template/login.html') # here i used login built-in function
                                                     # instead of using directly in urls.py
```

And i used `my_login` view in urls.py instead of `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'`

EDIT

```
New in Django 1.10:
The redirect_authenticated_user parameter was added.
```

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I believe that the easiest way is to do a verification inside the`view` that handles your login:

```
if(request.user.is_authenticated):
    return redirect('/'); #homepage, whatever
else:
    ....
```

Comment: I am using the builtin views, so as I understand it I can't modify them. Am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

In your login method check whether the user in the request context is logged in or not. If so redirect that user to another view, if not let him see the login view.

```
 def login_page(request):

   username = password = ''
   loginForm = LoginForm

  if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('usernameInput')
    password = request.POST.get('passwordInput')
    next = request.POST.get('nextInput')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            state = "User successfully logged in!"

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
        else:
            state = "Your account is not active"
    else:
        state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
  else:
    print('form was not posted')

  variables=RequestContext(request,{
    'form':loginForm
  })
  return render_to_response('login.html',variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **class based views** (CBVs) is on the rise. This approach will help you redirect to another url when accessing view for non authenticated users only.

In my example the **sign-up** page overriding the `get()` method.

```
class Signup(CreateView):
    template_name = 'sign-up.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('path/to/desired/url')
        else:
            # Omit the form if you are not using it.
            form = self.form_class() 
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

You can also do this on `dispatch()` method of the View class for simplicity sake.

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('path/to/desired/url')
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Cheers!