# Django Shows Auth Login Page when Already Logged In

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

My URL for login is

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html',
     'extra_context': {'next': '/tasks/home/',
                       'title': 'Taskman | Log In'},
```

and it does successful login, but when i type "/user/login" again as the URL, it again displays login page after successful login.

So does Django doesn't handle this case?

As `login` views shows

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

So do i have to overwrite `AuthenticationForm`?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, I hope it work for you:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43157465/7309662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior I have always seen with Django - even if you are logged in, and you attempt to navigate to the login page, it will display the login page. This is useful behavior in some cases, for example if a person has multiple user accounts they can login as, it means they can log in to a different user account without having to log out first.

If you wish to override this behavior, you could do this by having a login URL point to a `RedirectView` that:

- If the user is already logged in, redirects them to a specific page (and ideally, if there is a next page parameter provided in the URL, it directs them to that).
- If the user is not logged in, redirects them to the actual login prompt view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By specifying my own Views, i am not able to use default authentication system. if i am not wrong?

Comment: Yes you can still use the standard authentication system no problem, what I am suggesting is the login URL that you expose to the users can point at your own custom view, which redirects the users to the default authentication systems login view if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Now my view looks somethings like this,

Comment: so do i have to authenticate user first and then pass that object to login function. But i want rendering of login page as well from default login function.

Comment: You need to return a `HttpResponseRedirect` from the redirect view