# How to make Login and register link dissapear after I login

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want login and register link to disappear after I login, and instead logout link should appear after being logged in. How would I achieve that[image]

Comment: i think this question id duplicated check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946446/logged-in-users-still-see-login-page-django-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you can make these opitional, like:

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="...">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Register</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="...">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">{{ request.user.username }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this question is duplicated i would be a pleasure if you assign this question as duplicated

Comment: @Joseph: the linked question does solve something else: it asks for a redirect in case the user has logged in, and aims to visit the login page.

Comment: i know but it the same logic I guess

Comment: @Joseph: no, a direct is something else than rendering content in a template. The person that answered the question understood it the wrong way. Look at the endit. Redirecting means that the view is not "accessible" (as in you get a 301 response), whereas rendering the template will result in a 200, but with some content partially missing.